# ActionMailer not sending emails in Development on Windows 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I cannot seem to send emails out in the Development environment when I run my Rails project from my Windows 7 machine. I keep getting a permission denied error. When I run the same code on my Mac the emails are sent out. This led me to believe it could be Windows firewall settings but despite turning the Firewall off and disabling my anti-virus I still get the same error below:

> Permission denied - connect(2)
>
> C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `initialize'
>
> C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `open'
>
> C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `tcp_socket'
>
> C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `block in do_start'
>
> C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:65:in `timeout'
>
> C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:549:in `do_start'
>
> C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:519:in `start' mail (2.5.4)
>
> lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!' mail
>
> (2.5.4) lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery' mail (2.5.4)
>
> lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `block in deliver'

In development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Setup_Mail initializer:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address            => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port               => 587,
    :domain             => 'mydomain.com',
    :authentication     => 'plain',
    :user_name          => 'info@mydomain.com',
    :password           => 'secret'
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your `development.rb` SMTP settings.